# .htaccess - Restrict allowed file types within subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

**Context**

I'm trying to create a white list of file types and disable directory listing on a directory named `upload` by using .htaccess. For security reasons, I do not want to place the .htaccess file within the `upload` directory. Instead it will be placed one level up in the file hierarchy.

**Issue**

I'm getting a 500 HTTP response on the entire website.

**Contents of .htaccess**

```
<Directory upload>
Options -Indexes
deny from all
<Files ~ “^w+.(gif|jpe?g|png)$”>
order deny,allow
allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

UPDATE: Here's the apache error log

**Error log**

```
[Sun Feb 14 19:31:52 2016] [alert] [client ::1] /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bombeiros/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
```

Comment: error log will have details of the 500.

Comment: @covener Thanks. I've added the error log above. Do you know the reason behind?

Comment: Ok, I didn't know but <directory> is not allowed within .htaccess. It needs to be in httpd.conf.